# Affine cipher and shift cipher

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I have the following question:

> An affine cipher with key $K(0,b)$ is equivalent to a shift cipher explain why

I don't think this is true, and assume it is a typo, $K(1,b)$ I would agree, since this is the same as a shift cipher since:
 $$X=1x+b\Leftrightarrow X=x+b$$ is just a shift cipher with shift $b$.

Comment: It has to be a typo! For one thing $\operatorname{gcd}(a,26)=1$ so $a=0$ is out of the question by all means!

Comment: @String I thought it must be, but it is on a past exam, how could they possible do that on a final!

Comment: I have no idea! But for any $a$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(a,26)\neq 1$ the number a generates a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{26}$ of size less than $26$. So it is clearly impossible.

Comment: @string Thank you for clarification, my nerves have been settled!

Comment: That is great to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a typo.

The affine cipher key:$K(1,b)$ is exactly the shift cipher.